# MYSQL invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php

Hi i have a form which has two check field in it, as shown below:

```
 <td><input type='checkbox' name='checked[]' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input type='checkbox' name='notsure[]' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>&nbsp;</td>
```

what i am trying to do is post this information to a PHP page to update the database although at the moment i am just trying to get the result to echo out so i can test it, but i keep getting the error shown above.

My PHP code is here:

```
 if (count($_POST['checked']>0)){
foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $key => $val){

    $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  echo "$val";
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. You should close the bracket for `count` function after the post variable, not after the `0`. It should be `if (count($_POST['checked']) > 0) {`. When you fix this the code should work. The other part seems OK.

Comment: use `print_r($_POST);` and see results and fit it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the name of the checkbox field eg:,

```
if (!empty($_POST['checked'])){
   foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $checked){
       // Your code goes here.
   }
}
```